# Error:Execution failed for task ':packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. not regarding libs

Tags: android, gradle, android-multidex

> Error:Execution failed for task ':packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
>    java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: R$array.class

Its not regarding lib dependencies

how to fix this

Comment: Did you google this error message?

Comment: Yes but all answers are about duplicated dependencies.

Comment: that is because duplicate dependencies cause thinks error

Comment: In my case it is not because of duplicated dependencies

Comment: How do you know? Why evidence do you hand to support your claim?

Comment: I don't know, someone advised me, and I tried, and it's did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do gradle clean: Run gradle task clean